# Mechanical Relay Question

Tags: arduino, relay

I found this picture explaining a G5V-2-H1-DC5 relay from Omron. My question is if Pin 5/6 can be a higher voltage than 5V while keeping the voltage at Pin 2 at 5V. Also, is there a limit to how fast the voltage at Pin 5/6 can change?

[image: G5V-2-H1-DC5 Relay from Omoron]

Comment: what does the spec sheet say about the maximum voltage that can be switched?

Comment: i just read it has a max switching voltage of 125 vdc but the relay has a coil voltage of 5V. i guess that means that the switching voltage does not have to be 5V. Does it matter how fast this voltage change though? For example, can i have a PWM signal driving the led at pin 5/6.

Comment: No. It does not matter.

Comment: @cjj: "*i guess that means that the switching voltage does not have to be 5V.*" should read "the **switched** voltage. The switching voltage is the 5 V feeding the coil. The switched voltage is that running through the contact. You should always post a link to the datasheet for the part under discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It's an electomagnetic machine, you turn on the electromagnet by putting voltage across pins 2 and 9 and a metal piece moves changing the connection from being 5-6-1`to being 5-6-10, so it doesn't care about thye nature of the circuit it switching so long as the act of switching it does not cause it to overheat.

As for frequency. I personally have put 13.56Mhz (at low power) through ordinary power switching relays (Panasonic JW1 series) and it worked well enough for my putposes, I was using what I had on-hand

There should be no problem switching a PWM drive for your LEDs

Comment: Need to respect the voltage and power limits for those contacts...

Comment: yeah, else you get a kind of localised overheating